# Linq to SQL - обновление

Tags: linq, sql

у меня такая проблема.
создал файл dbml (Linq to SQL), накидал туда таблицы из базы.
у меня сгенерировались классы со свойствами - названия полей из таблицы.
но, если я в таблицу из базы добавляю новое поле, то оно не создаётся как свойство класса, т.е. придётся удалить таблицу из dbml файла и опять её добавить.
есть ли какое-нибудь другое решение этой проблемы (без обновления файла dbml)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вам так важно использование именно Linq2Sql, то для генерации кода можете использовать sqlmetal. Это консольная утилита, позволяющая генерить код. Можете поставить её запуск в pre-build event.

Это не сильно гибкий подход, т.к. дизайнер предоставляет больше возможностей. Ещё Вы можете вручную создавать в дизайнере колонки, чтобы следовать за структурой БД. Только это надо делать очень аккуратно - ошибки при ручном редактировании табличных классов приводят к глюкам, по которым очень сложно понять, где ошибка.

Насколько я знаю, в Entity Framework что-то есть для синхронизации объектной модели и базы данных. Какую кнопку для этого надо нажать, не знаю.

Subsonic, NHibernate и XPO позволяют идти обратным путём: создаём объектную модель в коде, а при первом обращении к БД эти ORM синхронизируют структуру БД с ней. Но по опыту работы с XPO могу сказать, что гемора от этого будет только больше.